# How to fix Re-occuring error in Apex class Permission set assignment

Tags: apex, profile, permission-sets

to create a specific Permission to make a button we created available for specific roles, we had to include all of the Apex classes used for this and this error occured after saving :

```
common.exception.SqlDupValOnIndexException: ORA-00001: unique
constraint (CORE.AKSETUP_ENTITY_ACCESS) violated ORA-06512: at
"GRUMPY.UDDDMLSETUPENTITYACCESS", line 78 ORA-06512: at line 1 {call
UddDmlSetupEntityAccess.bulk_insert_detail(?,?,?,?)} {call
UddDmlSetupEntityAccess.bulk_insert_detail(?,?,?,?)}
```

does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You've run into a dwarf error (from Snow White), Grumpy. You should contact salesforce support.

Comment: Did you ever find resolution to this error? I just encountered while trying to add assign a managed app to a permission set group.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are not trying to add the same Apex class to the permission set.

I just got a similar error while trying to modify a permission set, trying to include flow permissions.
I had one flow in the permission set listed already and wanted to add more. As I selected all of them, including the one that I already had added before, I got the error. When I added one by one, not including the ones already listed, it worked.
It is probably a not treated error (or at least it was my case).